# PIC32 Real Time Clock and Calender. What is a use case?

Tags: pic, microchip

I have observed that some PIC32MX micro-controllers have an inbuilt RTCC peripherial.

The first feeling i had when i saw this was joy, as it meant i could eliminate a component of my PCB.

However my joy faded when i realized there was no way for the RTCC module to retain its values when the power to the PIC32 is cut off.

My question therefore is, what is the use case for this module if any at all.

PS: Part number is PIC32MX440F512H
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61143H.pdf

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet for the microcontroller you are considering, and tell us the specific part number.

Comment: Sure @ElliotAlderson. I have updated my question.

Comment: I believe the PIC32MX with RTCC also reserves a pin for battery back-up, unless you are required to put the MPU in a 'sleep' state, so the RTCC always has power. Either way PIC has a built in solution.

Comment: I guess you don't turn the power off to the PIC chip, but sleep it, so the CPU etc draws near zero power. It would then keep alive on a coin cell, or a supercap while you changed the main battery. It might have been nice to have a Vrtcc pin to power just that bit.

Comment: Page 121 of the PIC32MX family manual shows that the RTCC requires the MPU to be in a sleep state to keep the RTCC running.

Comment: @Sparky256 Yes, i have read the datasheet. However my application is powered from the mains supply. Power is not guaranteed to be on all the time. So i need to be able to retain time info during these "dark" periods. Clearly then, the use case is for LOW power applications where the PIC always has a source of power (battery powered) . Sticking to my DS3231M RTCC :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See page 121 of your datasheet:

> The  PIC32MX  RTCC  module  is  intended  for  applications  in  which
>   accurate  time  must  be  maintained  forextended periods of time with
>   minimal or no CPU intervention.  Low-power  optimization  provides 
>   extended battery lifetime while keeping track of time.

There, they also refer to this: [Section 29. Real-Time Clock and Calendar (RTCC)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61125F.pdf).

Comment: So clearly, it should only be used in ONLY battery powered applications if extended time keeping is required. My applications so far have all been powered from a not too stable mains supply. Thank you anyway

Comment: @GH_eng I'm not sure why you think so. I see no problem with a mains supply system that ***also*** can maintain the RTCC through the use of an additional battery.

Comment: The problem here is the mains supply around here is quite unstable. Also the device is to be placed in a facility that should not require manually setting the time anytime there is a power outage. A stand alone RTCC with a stand-by coin cell battery is what i opted for. Any hacks you might have are welcome :)

Comment: @GH_eng It is a trade-off. The stand-alone RTCC with battery is a very simple approach. Using the RTCC within the MCU saves you that IC, but complicates how you power the RTCC and also ties you more closely into a more limited subset of MCUs. Only you can work out the cost/benefit ratios of these options. I might very well go the same direction you are. I just can't say.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered specifically in section 29.6, "OPERATION IN POWER-SAVING MODES" of [the manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61125F.pdf).